# Pass parent directive's controller to a directive controller (like it is done in the "link" function)

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have several hierarchical directives and in one, I need to have some functions in its controller, so that the child elements can interact with it. But this one directive also needs to reference its parent directive's controller, but I don't know how to do that in controller (I know how in the "link()" but this time I need controller for the child interaction). It should be possible to do it with scope:

```
controller: function($scope){},
link: function (scope, ..., parentCtrl){
    scope.parentCtrl = parentCtrl;
}
```

but it seems weird, because the link function is executed after the controller is, or it it OK? I'm confused and I think it might be a bad design?

diagram:

```
ParentParentDirective
    controller: function(service){
        this.service = service;
    }

ParentDirective
    controller: function(){
        this.callOnService = function(id){
            ???ParentParentDirective???.service.callSth(id);
        }
    }

ChildDirective
    link(scope, ...,ParentDirectiveCtrl){
        scope.makeChanges = ParentDirectiveCtrl.callOnService;
    }
```

Comment: use `require: '^ParentDirective'`  or `require: '^^ParentParentDirective'`.  see https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive, near the bottom "Creating Directives that Communicate"

Answer (score 1):

You can use $element.controller method for that, as in example below.

```js
angular.module('app', []);

angular.module('app').directive('grandparent', function () {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    controller: function () {
      this.go = function () {
        console.log('Grandparent directive');
      };
    }
  };
});


angular.module('app').directive('parent', function () {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    controller: function () {
      this.go = function () {
        console.log('Parent directive');
      };
    }
  };
});

angular.module('app').directive('child', function () {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    require: ['^parent', '^grandparent'],
    controller: function ($element) {
      var parentCtrl = $element.controller('parent');
      var grandparentCtrl = $element.controller('grandparent');
      
      parentCtrl.go();
      grandparentCtrl.go();
    }
  };
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.5/angular.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app">
  <grandparent>
    <parent>
      <child></child>
    </parent>
  </grandparent>
</div>
```